# boost::bind how to define a function that takes a callback as argument

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I am trying to write a library module that invokes boost::asio operations.  This module would be used by an application logic layer for further processing, based on the results.

My requirement is plain and simple.  What all I need is to be able to specify a callback fn in my Util class below, that can take any function ptr, or boost::bind(member fn), or whatever, and invoke that callback, once the async code is complete.

```
class Util {
  public:
    void sendMsg(const Msg& m, <some callback fn here...>) {
       // Make a call to boost::asio approximately as below..
       boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
                   boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                   boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                    boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));

      // Here, I want to pass the "<some callback fn here>" to async_write,
      // instead of calling boost::bind here.  How to do that?
    }
};
```

So, my specific question is..
**What should my sendMsg signature look like?  I am unable to arrive at the fn signature, especially the callback part.**

Thanks to anyone letting me know how to do this.

Comment: `std::function`? Or a templated type?

Comment: okay.  I lost touch with much of c++ these days. Could you kindly provide a simple example.. pls

Comment: ok, thx for the hint.  i seem to have got it.  I am kind of old school c++. Getting familiar with boost, async stuff.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to lambdas, it's easy

```
class Util {
  public:
    template <typename _Proc>
    void sendMsg(const Msg& m, _Proc proc) 
    {
        shared_ptr<Util> pThis = shared_from_this;
        boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
            [&proc, =pThis/* , etra args */](boost::...::error_code ec, size_t bytes) // <- use capture to pass extra agruments and shared ptr
            {
               // use pThis !
               proc(/* etra args */);
               // or pthis->proc()
            });
        }

};
```

This will accept lambdas as well as std/boost::function

Comment: Thank you. But Y shared_ptr for Util class? The caller of Util::sendMsg is supposed to provide a callback fn, which I hv to pass to async_write. No?

Comment: The shared_ptr is passed by value to the calling object, either by the call to bind(), or by lambda capture.  It's only purpose it to keep the object alive while there is i/o operations or timers pending.  `this` will auto-destroy when the conversation with the client is over, unless you keep it somewhere else.  Usually, a message smart pointer is passed along.